# Continuity of Piecewise Functions with constants

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I have a piecewise function:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2-3x, &x < 4\\
j, &x = 4\\
k+x, &x > 4
\end{cases}$$

I want to find the values of $j$ and $k$ that makes my function continuous where $x = 4$.

How do I go about finding $j$ and $k$?

Comment: Hint: Look at the left and right limits as $x\to 4$.

Comment: I understand that j must be 4 but I cannot understand k.

Comment: It's the same idea.  Look at what happens to $k+x$ as $x\to 4$ and use that to figure out what $k$ has to be so they line up.

Comment: Still not following. Can you demonstrate please?

Comment: I think you're over complicating it.  What is $$\lim_{x\to 4} k+x \ ?$$

Comment: Suppose that $k=4$., then when $x\to 4$ from the right, you would have $f(4)=k+4=4+4=8$ which is not the same as the limit for when $x\to 4$ from the left (which we determined earlier was $4$).  Now, suppose $k=10$, then when $x\to 4$ from the right, you would have $f(4)=k+4=10+4=14$, again, different than the limit from the left.  So, $k=4$ and $k=10$ are both wrong choices here.  There is however a correct choice for a value of $k$ such that the limit as $x$ approaches $4$ from the right will make it line up with the others.

Comment: Ah, yes I am just overcomplicating it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 4$ if and only if 
$$\lim_{x \to 4} f(x) = f(4) $$

In order for the limit to exist, we must have:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 4^-} f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 4^+} f(x) \\
\lim_{x \to 4^-} \left[x^2 - 3x \right] &= \lim_{x \to 4^+} \left[k + x \right] \\
4^2 - 3(4) &= k + 4 \\
4 &= k+4 \\
k &= 0
\end{align*}

So in order for $f(x)$ to be continuous, we have:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2-3x & x < 4\\
j & x = 4\\
x & x > 4
\end{cases} $$
and we see that:
$$ \lim_{x \to 4} f(x) = 4 $$
Since continuity implies that the limit must equal $f(4) = j$, we have that $j = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

J=4,K=0.
Here you may use the LHS=RHS case.then you must find it out